# Do I cross-validate my entire dataset, even the validation and test set?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cross-validation

I have the following dataset where `binary_peak` is a binary response variable and I have (not shown) 9 explanatory variables (also binary).

```
    `binary_peak`   H3K18Ac H3K27me3    H3K36me3
1:00    0   0   0   0
2:00    0   0   0   0
3:00    0   0   0   0
4:00    0   0   0   0
5:00    0   0   0   0
---             
1903462:    0   0   1   0
1903463:    0   0   1   0
1903464:    0   0   0   0
1903465:    0   0   0   0
1903466:    0   0   1   0
```

I am a little bit confused about the cross validation procedure.  The way I am currently doing this is fitting a model on all 1.9 million rows.

```
 r1 = glm(formula = binding_peak ~ 1 + H3K18Ac + H3K27me3 + H3K36me3  
              family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
              data = massive_ds)
```

After this, I run $K = 10$-fold cross validation on the **entire dataset again**.

```
cv.glm(data = massive_ds, glmfit = r1, K = 10)
```

I believe my approach here is wrong. What I should be doing is splitting the entire dataset into two (or three?) sets:

1. Training Set
2. Validation Set
3. Test Set (??)

Does this mean that when I fit my model and perform K-fold validation, I am ONLY using the **training set?** I was under the impression that this is exactly what the K-fold cross validation does? That it breaks my entire dataset into groups, uses one group to train a model, and then apply the model on the remaining groups.

Also, how do I then apply this model to the dataset? My goal is to create ROC curves characterizing the model's accuracy, but if I am using the entire thing as a training/validation set (interally), would it be sufficient to just apply the model again on the training set?

Some background: I have data on biologically significant areas of the entire mouse genome. The genome is split into bins of 200 basepairs, and the response variable (binary) indicates whether a bin is  of interest or not. Once I get confirmation that I need to, indeed, split my entire dataset I would take `chr 1 - 6` as a training set and use the rest as a validation set.

Answer (score 5):

The syntax for `cv.glm` is clouding the issue here.

In general, one divides the data up into $k$ folds. The first fold is used as the test data, while the remaining $k-1$ folds are used to build the model. We evaluate the model's performance on the first fold and record it. This process is repeated until each fold is used once as test data and $k-1$ times as training data. There's no need to fit a model to the entire data set.

**However**, `cv.glm` is a bit of a special case. If you look at its [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/boot/html/cv.glm.html) for `cv.glm`, you do need to fit an entire model first. Here's the example at the very end of the help text:

```
require('boot')
data(mammals, package="MASS")
mammals.glm <- glm(log(brain) ~ log(body), data = mammals)
(cv.err <- cv.glm(mammals, mammals.glm)$delta)
(cv.err.6 <- cv.glm(mammals, mammals.glm, K = 6)$delta)
```

The 4th line does a leave-one-out validation (each fold contains one example), while the last line performs a 6-fold cross-validation.

This *sounds* problematic: using the same data for training and testing is a sure-fire way to bias your results, but **it is actually okay.** If you look at [the source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/index.html) (in `bootfuns.q`, starting at line 811), the overall model is not used for prediction. The cross-validiation code just extracts the formula and other fitting options from the model object and reuses those for the cross-validation, which is fine* and then cross-validation is done in the normal leave-a-fold-out sort of way.

It outputs a list and the `delta` component contains two estimates of the cross-validated prediction error. The first is the raw prediction error (according to your cost function or the average squared error function if you didn't provide one) and the second attempts to adjust to reduce the bias from not doing leave-one-out-validation instead. The [help text](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/boot/html/cv.glm.html) has a citation, if you care about why/how. These are the values I would report in my manuscript/thesis/email-to-the-boss and what I would use to build an ROC curve.

---

* I say fine, but it *is* annoying to fit an entire model just to initialize something. You might think you could do something clever like

```
my.model <- glm(log(brain) ~ log(body), data=mammals[1:5, :])
cv.err <- cv.glm(mammals, my.model)$delta
```

but it doesn't actually work because it uses the $y$ values from the overall model instead of the `data` argument to `cv.glm`, which is silly. The entire function is less than fifty lines, so you could also just roll your own, I guess.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose my entire dataset is called $Z$ (1.9m rows). What about the approach of splitting $Z$ into two sets $A$ (training) and $B$ (test). Here I fit a model on $A$ and perform k-fold validation on $A$ as well. The validation will split $A$ up into $k$ groups (validation and training) and give me my error estimates. After I have a completed model, I can then apply this model on $B$ to assess its accuracy. In other words, $B$ doesn't even come into play until I have a fit model on hand and I pretend the only dataset I have is $A$. Would this be a suitable (and better approach)?

Comment: It's hard to say. I've heard @FrankHarrell say that you need an astronomical number of points for a pure train/test split to work well, but 950,000 points is probably enough. That said, people don't often report totally held-out results, so you might be better off increasing $k$ instead. The cross-validated results are nearly unbiased but with high variance, so a larger $k$ than the typical $k=10$ could help you drive down the variance. That's probably what I would do.

Comment: Thanks. So in other words, if it were you, you'd just drive $k$ up and perform model fitting on the entire 1.9million row dataset? If so, how would I test its accuracy then? My goal is to create ROC curves.

Comment: My first version might have been a little unclear. Although you have to fit the entire model first, the subsequent cross-validation is actually valid; the first step is just an artifact of how the authors of 'boot' wrote the code. 

I suggested trying a much larger $k$ since 10-fold CV estimates often have pretty large variance (as you'd expect from averaging together only 10 numbers). Jackknife/n-fold cross-validation has its own problems, but I think you'd be on pretty safe ground with k=100 (if you wanted smaller standard errors).

Comment: Holding the data completely out is nice, but 1) you don't get any measure of uncertainty with a single test set, though. I suppose you could bootstrap from it or something and 2) It's most convincing if you can claim that the experimenters had absolutely no access to it before testing.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I am still a little bit confused. If I use my entire dataset to train the model (and perform CV which only gives me a delta value, so I don't even know HOW to properly utilize CV), at what point do I test the model? In other words, I'd like to assess the performance of this model by seeing if it can indeed predict what is of interest. So would it be sufficient to just split my entire dataset $Z = A + B$ and set $B$ as my validation set? So I'd train my model and perform CV only on $A$.

Comment: We posted almost at the same time. I guess your comment answered my question, but I don't really grasp the concept of it. If you don't mind, could you break it down for me? (maybe we can continue this in chat). I am actually more confused about what CV does.. All it returns (in R) is the delta vector which is some error estimate. I am not sure how this helps me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26276/discussion-between-matt-krause-and-masfenix).